# Android Rotating a handle like Animation

Tags: android, animation, rotation, handle

I have an image shown below:

[image]

I want to rotate this handle when user slides it down. What would be the best way to do this? Whether to run a strip of images when user slides or something else?
Any code example would be appreciated...

Comment: 1. make layout with imageview ... 2. put this image there ... 3. ask user to throw their device ... 4. homework ? i saw similar question here on SO

Comment: i did sample project for ya .... http://esilo.pl/selvin/rotation.zip

Comment: @Selvin I know its my homework. I am asking for an idea solution. and thanks for your comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use Code from below link, may be it will solve your problem

[Image Rotation Example](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/)